# Does CoverageInfoManager support multi-threading?

Tags: c#, xml, mstest, code-coverage

Currently my project is using CoverageInfoManager to convert MSTest code coverage to xml. See code below

```
  foreach(var coverageFile  in coverageFolder)
  {
       CoverageInfoManager.ExePath = "<executable_search_paths>";
       CoverageInfoManager.SymPath = "<symbol_search_paths>";
       CoverageInfo info = CoverageInfoManager.CreateInfoFromFile(coverageFile); 
       CoverageDS dataSet = info.BuildDataSet(null); 
       CoverageInfoManager.Shutdown();
 }
```

Since there many coverage file I want to process, so I want to process file in multi-thread way, in C# it could be like this:

```
       Parallel.ForEach(coverageFiles, coverageFile =>
       {
             CoverageInfoManager.ExePath = "<executable_search_paths>";
             CoverageInfoManager.SymPath = "<symbol_search_paths>";
             CoverageInfo info = CoverageInfoManager.CreateInfoFromFile("coverageFile "); 
             CoverageDS dataSet = info.BuildDataSet(null); 
             CoverageInfoManager.Shutdown();
       });
```

by running this code, there is an exception on

```
 CoverageInfo info = CoverageInfoManager.CreateInfoFromFile("coverageFile ");
```

Exception message :

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '2383aa6b-a3b9-434c-8fc0-ebca44056838'  Key being added: '2383aa6b-a3b9-434c-8fc0-ebca44056838'
```

Does anybody know if the code can work on multi-thread way? or is there some other way to make it run faster when lots coverage files need to be processed?

Thank you guys!

Comment: What is the full namespace (and assembly name) of "CoverageInfoManager" ?